# In an iOS application, what is typically considered the model in the MVC paradigm?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, model-view-controller, model

I'm trying to understand the MVC paradigm, and I understand that the model is the data layer. I'm confused as to how that manifests specifically in applications however.

Say I have a Core Data database of `Animal` objects/entities (with properties such as genus, region, etc.). Is the Core Data database considered the model? Is the `Animal` class considered the model?

Could anyone offer a practical explanation of what a model would be in a typical iOS application?

Answer (score 0):

Model has your application logic/algorithm/computations, manipulation of the data etc. View is the presentation, and receives user interactions. Controller orchestrates the application and the flow to another controller and interactions with the view and the model.

So, in your example if there is certain rules that are to be followed before data is stored in DB or returned to the view (user), that will go in your model. It could well be your animal class.

Answer (score 0):

-The **Model** is the brain of the application. It does the calculations and creates a virtual world for itself that can live without the views and controllers. In other words, think of a model as a virtual copy of your application, without a face!

-A **View** is the window through which your users interact with your application. It displays what’s inside the model most of the time, but in addition to that, it accepts users' interactions. Any interaction between the user and your application is sent to a view,which then can be captured by a view controller and sent to the model.

-**Controllers** in iOS programming usually refer to view controllers. Think of view controllers as a bridge between the model and your views. They interpret what is happening on one side (what the user does on the view side, or the information provided by the model) and use that information to alter the other side as needed.